# How to email with attachment on android 2.3 devices?

Tags: android, email, android-intent, email-attachments

I just want to send an intent off to gmail with an image attachment. the following code works PERFECTLY on all 4.0+ devices, but fails on my motorola razr 2.3. why??? how do i get it to work below 4.0 devices?

I have the following code:

```
public class SimpleEmailAttachmentActivity extends Activity {
private static final String sFileName = "myfile.png";
private Bitmap bitmap;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_email_attachment);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_snapshot_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View paramView) {
            View rootView = button.getRootView();
            if(rootView != null) {
                rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap drawingCache = rootView.getDrawingCache();
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawingCache);
                rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            }

            saveToInternalStorage(bitmap);

            File file = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + sFileName);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"blah@blah.com"});
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "email subject here");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "email body here");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            intent.setType("plain/text");

            startActivity(intent);              
        }
        });
    }

private void saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmap){
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(sFileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this example to email with attachment

```
public class MailImageFile extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

            public MailImageFile(){}

     public void Mail(String user, String pass) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator()           {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("abc@gmail.com", "pqr123%");
            }
            });
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,     InternetAddress.parse("xyz@gmail.com"));
    message.setContent(_multipart);
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setContent("Hi...", "text/html; charset=utf-8");

            Transport.send(message);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

//Got this solution form here

```
  private Multipart _multipart; 
_multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

public void addAttachment(String filename,String subject) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 
    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    BodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    messageBodyPart2.setText(subject); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2); 
} 


    }
```